# Unsubscribe on RxJS subscriber onCompleted, is it redundant?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'd like to know if this code has any sense or not:

```
let subs : Subscription;

// getObjectInfo retrieves object information from a MySQL DB
subs = this.ObjectService.getObjectInfo(item.id_obj)
        .subscribe(
          (retObject : any) => {
            // Process object here
          },
          (error) => {
            // Error in API call
          },
          () => {
            // IS THIS REDUNDANT OR UNNECESSARY?
            subs.unsubscribe();
          });
```

What I pretend is to make sure that the subscription is finished as soon as I get the info from the DB and I process it, but I don't know if this is a good way or if it's unnecessary...

The reason I'm asking this is because I see duplicate API calls sometimes and I wonder if they are because I didn't finish the subscriptions in a proper way or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to call `.unsubscribe()` when the Observable completes. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's what I wanted to know. Regarding the linked article, I'm using the `takeWhile` operator in more complex components to unsubscribe from all subscriptions when the component is destroyed, but I've seen a more interesting method in the article (the `takeUntil` operator), so I'll do some tests. Cheers!

Comment: @martin you often need a crystal ball to know if an observable will complete on it's own. I'm just saying that when they designed observable they made this simple fact hard to be sure of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `take` or `first`:

```js
this.ObjectService.getObjectInfo(item.id_obj)
    .take(1) // or first()
    .subscribe(...)
```

So it will automatically unsubscribe after the first emission

Comment: Hi, I'll give a try to the `first` operator, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think `take` throws an error if the count isn't emitted. While `first` will not throw an error if none are emitted. I once spent 2 days tracking down a bug because I used the wrong one.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind, thanks for the annotation, @cgTag.

Comment: @cgTag @Fel `take` doesn't throw, unless you use a negative parameter